# Create unique one to one number from 2 numbers

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory, functions, elementary-set-theory, random

A smilar question has been asked before [Create unique number from 2 numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23503/create-unique-number-from-2-numbers).

> is there some way to create unique number from 2 positive integer numbers? Result must be unique even for these pairs: 2 and 30, 1 and 15, 4 and 60. In general, if I take 2 random numbers result must be unique(or with very high probability unique)**Mine should be Unique**
>
> Thanks a lot
>
> EDIT: calculation is for computer program,so computational complexity is important

The aceepted answer suggest the user to use Cantor pairing function which I tried to program it like this:

> To calculate π(47, 32):
>
> 47 + 32 = 79,
>
> 79 + 1 = 80,
>
> 79 × 80 = 6320,
>
> 6320 ÷ 2 = 3160,
>
> 3160 + 32 = 3192,
>
> so π(47, 32) = 3192.
>
> To find x and y such that π(x, y) = 1432:
>
> 8 × 1432 = 11456,
>
> 11456 + 1 = 11457,
>
> √11457 = 107.037,
>
> 107.037 − 1 = 106.037,
>
> 106.037 ÷ 2 = 53.019,
>
> ⌊53.019⌋ = 53,
>
> so w = 53;
>
> 53 + 1 = 54,
>
> 53 × 54 = 2862,
>
> 2862 ÷ 2 = 1431,
>
> so t = 1431;
>
> 1432 − 1431 = 1,
>
> so y = 1;
>
> 53 − 1 = 52,
>
> so x = 52; thus π(52, 1) = 1432.

π(a,b)=12(a+b)(a+b+1)+b.

But the Canton Pairing doesn't always create a unique number based on the two numbers used e.g:

a=73114279

b=1

π(a,b)=663902325

But when you inverse it, using the inverse fomular such that:

π(x,y)=663902325

You would get

π(-536868496,536884434)=663902325

My question is: What formular can I use so that I can always get a unique number from just two numbers, though the formular must be inversible such that:

(a,b)=c
(b,a)=d

But when you inverse it, using the inverse fomular such that:

You would get
c=(a,b)
d=(b,a)

Comment: What do you need this **for**? Your practical needs will to a large degree determine what you _should_ be using, and the nice _looking_ formulas such as the zig-zag function may not be what makes the most sense in practice.

Comment: E.g. in most practical cases you will not be working with the whole infinite $\mathbb N$, but with machine integers of a particular fixed width. In that setting simply concatenating those fixed-width integers is much simpler and more efficient for many purposes.

Comment: I'm using it in a Java program, concatenating it wouldn't be helpful, though it would be fast. And as you noted I would be within a fixed range of integer which in Java is not more than 2 billion. So you see why concatenating would also be a bad idea assuming I have 243425 and 478363, concatenating both would really go beyond the 2 billion limits. Though negative numbers too are welcomed.

Comment: If you have two `int`s as input and want a single `int` as output, you _will_ get collisions. There's no way around that. Again **what do you need this for**? (Yes, I see that your secret use of this function is in a Java program, but you have not told what that use **is**).

Comment: "π(-536868496,536884434)=663902325" $-536868496$ isn't a positive integer.

Comment: @fleablood, Yes it's not a positive integer, but still give same answer as the other values

Comment: "but still give same answer as the other values"  So?  If it's not positive than it doesn't count.  Are there any other *positive* pairs that give the same answer?  If not you don't have a problem.

Comment: It is most likely best to ask in the cryptographic stack exchange because what you want is a hash function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If order is important--i.e., the number you create from $(a,b)$ must be different from $(b,a)$--then exploit the Unique Factorization Theorem to create the number:

$n = {\rm Prime}[a]^2 \rm{Prime}[b]$ where ${\rm Prime}[a]$ is the $a^{th}$ prime number.

- ${\rm Prime}[2]^2 {\rm Prime}[30] = 1017$
- ${\rm Prime}[1]^2 {\rm Prime}[15] = 188$
- ${\rm Prime}[4]^2 {\rm Prime}[60] = 13769$

In *Mathematica*:

```
f[a_Integer, b_Integer] := Prime[a]^2 Prime[b]
```

For two numbers above $10^9$, this takes $0.030089$ seconds on a Mac laptop.  Not wasteful at all... extremely efficient...  And of course provably unique.

Of course, to go backward, you merely perform a Factorization:

```
FactorInteger[1017]
```

(* {{3, 2}, {113, 1}} *)

which means $1017 = 3^2 \times 113$

This tells you that the first element, $a$, is such that the $a^{th}$ prime is $3$, and the second element, $b$, is such that the $b^{th}$ prime is $113$.

You can easily and efficiently find these numbers:

```
PrimePi[3]
```

(* 2 *)

```
PrimePi[113]
```

(* 30 *)

In simple, efficient code:

```
reversef[n_Integer] := PrimePi[#] & /@ FactorInteger[n][[All, 1]]
```

So for the example you requested:

```
reversef[1445]
```

(* {3,7} *)

Comment: Order is important, as I mentioned at the last example (a,b)=c and (b,a)=d. Therefore d=(b,a) and c=(a,b).

Comment: That is all well and good for theoretical purposes, but wasteful and slow in practice.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the formula above, but can you simpify it in simple english. As I'm not really a mathematician nor do I know how to convert this into a program. Example of simplification: is like the way I solved the Cantor pairing function. I know I'm asking for much of your time, but that would really be helpful.
I'm using it in a java program, so knowing it in simple English, would help me write the code in Java.

Comment: @kingamanda:  If you don't know the Unique Factorization Theorem--widely considered the foundational theorem of mathematics, or at least number theory--I'm afraid I cannot help you.

Comment: Without knowing the use case, it's of course impossible to know whether 0.03 seconds for an operation as simple as this is good enough, but it certainly seems wasteful and inefficient.

Comment: "that is all well and good for theoretical purposes, but wasteful and slow in practice."  What practice? The op asked for a way to get unique numbers that is invertible.  This is that.

Comment: @HenningMakholm writes:  "In that setting simply concatenating those fixed-width integers is much simpler and more efficient for many purposes."  Why would you ever assume the numbers are fixed width when *none* of the three explicit examples given by the OP have that property?

Comment: An example of what David G. Stork is suggesting is that $(3,7)\mapsto \text {third prime}^2\times \text{seventh prime}= 5^2\times 17 = 425$ and $(7,3) \mapsto \text {seventh prime}^2\times \text{third prime}= 17^2\times 5 = 1445$.  It should be clear that the terms are unique.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: They say they're using it in a computer program, and in that context it will hard for them to _have_ numbers that are not fixed width, unless they're making special efforts to use bignums. I'm guessing that probably they're not.

Comment: Thank you @fleablood. Now how can I inverse it such that 1445 gives me (7,3)?

Comment: @kingamanda:  See my updated answer....

Comment: Every number has a unique prime factorization.  $1445 = 5*17^2$.  So $(a,b)$ will be so that $17$ is the $a$th prime and $5$ is the $b$th prime.  And $17$ is the 7th prime and $5$ is the 3rd so $a = 7; b= 3$.

Comment: @king amada:  As far as I see, my efficient code performs everything you requested.  I will contribute no more, since I haven't even received a single up-vote, let alone an acceptance.  Good luck in your studies.

Comment: Sorry, @DavidG.Stork I was busy doing other assignments, I really appreciate your time and efforts, also I will write the code in Java as soon as I'm done with other assignments, I will then vote your answer once it works in java. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, I just finished programming it, though it works... but as Henning pointed out, I'm bound by int max. So using your method will eventually overflow the 32bit int.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments you say you want to use your function in a Java program where it looks like you want it to have a signature more or less like

```
static int pair(int a, int b) {
     ...
}
```

However, then you're out of luck: It is **impossible** for a pure function with this signature to always give different outputs for different inputs. Even if you restrict yourself to nonnegative inputs, there are $2^{31}\cdot 2^{31}=2^{62}$ possible inputs to the function and only $2^{32}$ possible output values, so by the pigeonhole principle there *must* be some output values that are produced by more than a single input pair.

In your question you quote the Cantor pairing function $\pi(a,b)=\frac12(a+b)(a+b+1)+1$ and claim that
$$\pi(73114279, 1) =663902325$$
But this result is wrong. The actual value of $\pi(73114279, 1)$ is $2672849006516341$ -- the smaller number you're seeing is the effect of arithmetic overflow when your Java program tries to multiply $73114280 \times 73114281$ and the result of that doesn't fit in an `int`.

Something, therefore, has to give. Depending on what you need the pairing for, I think you have basically these options:

- Let the output be a `long` instead of an `int`. In that case I would forget about the Cantor pairing function and simply do a binary concatenation of the two values:

  ```
  static long pair(int a, int b) {
     return ((long)a << 32) + (b & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
  }
  ```
- Decide that you won't be able to handle inputs so large that the pairing function overflows. In that case you might *still* want to do a simple concatenation:

  ```
  /** a and b should not be more than 65536 */
  static int pair(int a, int b) {
     return (a<<16) + b;
  }
  ```
- Accept that there will sometimes be collisions and deal with them somehow. What you want may be simply a *hash function* -- for example run `a` through one of the functions suggested [here](https://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/integer.html) and add `b`.
- Use `BigInteger` instead. (The lazy option, but I think the chance that it is actually best for you is quite small).
- Drop the idea of representing your two integers as one *number* and instead use simply an `int[]` or an object with two `int` fields `a` and `b`. (Even lazier, and better in many contexts).

Answer (score 1):

I showed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3003672/convert-infinite-2d-plane-integer-coords-to-1d-number/3003770#3003770) how to adapt the Cantor pairing function to accept negative as well as positive arguments.  It is not a complex calculation, a few adds and one multiply.  The problem is that the number you get is approximately four times the square of the sum of the absolute values of the two input numbers.  If those numbers are even about $32{,}000$ the result will overflow $32$ bits.  There is no way around it.  If your input numbers have $16$ bits there are $2^{16}$ of them, so there are $2^{32}$ pairs of them and you will overflow.  What is your objective for combining two numbers into one?